# Add and remove dynamic class names a-d?

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple buttons that need to change class on-click. I've managed to piece together some working code but wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this? Open to all languages and solutions.

Also, is there any benefit of wrapping the **(document).ready** around the **(document).on**?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.a', function() {
    $('.a').addClass('b');
    $('.a').removeClass('a');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.b', function() {
    $('.b').addClass('c');
    $('.b').removeClass('b');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.a {
  background: #bbb;
}

.b {
  background: orange;
}

.c {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">a</div>
<br>
<div class="a">a</div>
```

Comment: This is the standard way to handle dynamic class changes in jQuery.

Comment: You don't need to use `document.ready()` if you're delegating from `document`. But often delegation should be done from a more specific container element, and then you need to wait for the document to be ready.

Comment: Are you trying to change the class of all buttons with a given class or just the specific button that was clicked?

Comment: If I click an .a class button that will change ALL .a class buttons to .b. And so on .b changes all .b to .c.

Comment: While your code is succinct if you just want to go a->b->c [stop], you *can* use a single event handler to loop through classes, something like: https://jsfiddle.net/op64ga0m/1/  This will allow you to change the array of classes, without needing to rewrite the code / easily add new "steps". eg (compare with first link) https://jsfiddle.net/op64ga0m/2/